# git diff: how to see only staged/cached/indexed differences?

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to see a context diff for only my indexed changes with `git diff`.

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
C:\GitProject\DiffTestProject [master +0 ~1 -0]> git diff
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 07d4aba..e9944e6 100644
Binary files a/a.txt and b/a.txt differ
```

Comment: Try `diff -a` to force all files to be examined as text files.

Comment: @tripleee it's can run in my .txt  .thank you very much , You explain My doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

```shell
git diff filename # see uncommitted changes
git diff --cached # see the difference between index and last commit.
```

Comment: johnMa thanks u reply . i'm try this command , but it's not my want result , Thanks you : )